# Webrequest not working on IIS8 with SSL

Tags: c#, iis, ssl

Code for sending the request and its calling https

```
request =(HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(url);

request.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(AcceptAllCertifications);
request.Timeout = 5000;
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.81 Safari/537.36";
request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;
```

```
public bool AcceptAllCertifications(object sender, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate certification, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain chain, System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
    return true;
}
```

This code is working fine on my local system, but when we deploy this on IIS then it can not send request.

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: No i did not get any error i check it can not send request from IIS but request is going on local system and getting proper respons

Comment: You're going to have to give us some more code to work with. Link the `AcceptAllCertifications` code, and put the code in a try/catch block with a log to investigate the cause of the issue.

Comment: public bool AcceptAllCertifications(object sender, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate certification, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain chain, System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
        {
            return true;
        }

This code is for AcceptAllCertifications

Comment: Edit your original post, and include that there in the future. This appears to not be the problem. If it's not working, then you should be getting an exception somewhere, and I would make sure that it's being logged somewhere.

Comment: I put this code in try catch block but not get any exception and try to get status by ((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription  this code but response is null

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79837/discussion-between-dinesh-pipple-and-frankerz).

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved issue was on the server. Updated IIS host file comment unnecessary IP